# How to navigate to the particular line in eclipse by using the log

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

May i know How to navigate to the particular line in eclipse by using the log ?
example - 
Assuming this is already implemented with plugin NavigateUsingLog , when activated 
accepts a line something like below . And navigates to that particular line in eclipse IDE .

195     at com.MyProject.ui.home.SomClassName.SomeMethodName(SomClassName.java:40) ~[classes/:na]

I am aware how to navigate to a class, then go to function, then goto line number . i would like to save key strokes .
I have implemented this myself in source insight, and it helped us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the **Console View**, use the local menu to open a new **Java Stack Trace Console** and paste that line into it. It should let you hold down Ctrl/Cmd and use the parenthetical part with the line number as a hyperlink.

http://jeremyfranklin-ross.com/2013/11/eclipse-java-stack-trace-console/

Comment: i would like to do this in following steps - 
1) copy the line from log file
2) open a plugin with a keyboard shortcut 
3) paste the line 
with these 3 keystrokes , navigate to the corresponding code .